# Laravel: Created a service but class is not found

Tags: php, class, laravel, namespaces

Created the following file:

File: `App\Services\Custom\Auth\AuthService.php`

Name space: `App\Services\Custom\Auth`

Class name: `AuthCustom`

Method inside: `foo()`

In my controller I'm trying to call the foo method from the Service I created.
`App\Services\Custom\Auth\AuthService\AuthCustom::foo()`

Why does it keep returning `Class 'App\Services\Custom\Auth\Authservice\AuthCustom' not found`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

EDIT: 
I added this in the composer.json and run composer dump-autoload without errors.
And it works!

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Services/Custom/Auth/AuthService.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you have something in your composer.json that maps `App\Custom\Auth` to `App\Services\Custom\Auth`? Without it, you're missing `Services` in your namespace

Comment: I tried adding App\Services\Custom\Auth\AuthService::class in the providers but doesn't work

Comment: I think the problem is that it is not a ServiceProvider ?

Answer (score 1):

Your namespace does not match your directory structure. If your class is in `App\Services\Custom\Auth\AuthService.php`, then your namespace needs to be `App\Services\Custom\Auth`. If you really want your namespace to be `App\Custom\Auth`, then your file needs to be `App\Custom\Auth\AuthService.php`.

Once you fix this, make sure you do a `composer dump-autoload` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't run `composer dump-autoload` or `php composer.phar dump-autoload`.

The composer.json is very important for autoloading!

Comment: What exactly do I add in the config/app.php?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. For example service providers must be added to the providers array in your app.php. But a class works as follows: the first line of your php script is: `namespace App\Custom\Auth;`, so the composer.json autoload the right classes (your namespace must be routed to a file with the class). Did you change the default namespace `App`?

Comment: No I didn't. Haven't added it to the autoload composer. Will try thanjs

Answer (score 0):

Laravel needs an big file with all your php files required, usually generated via calling either artisan or composer with : php artisan dump-autoload  /  composer dump-autoload

It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.

More details: http://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/

Comment: FYI, the site linked here is broken